# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout contentInsets with estimated values for its dimensions

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Q: How do you apply `contentInsets` to a `group` whenever you use `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` where the axis uses estimated values for its dimension?

I have a simple app where I fetch some online data and then display the data to the user in a `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`.

The layout is using estimated values for the height dimensions (because I don't know the sizes until the data has loaded) and I want to set `contentInsets` on the `group`.

```
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(100))
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(100))
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])

// Set content insets on the group, which is not allowed for estimated dimensions.
group.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)

let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)

collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

The problem I'm facing is that setting `contentInsets` on the group is not allowed according to the documentation whenever you use **estimated** dimensions (and Xcode also gives a warning in the console):

> The value of this property is ignored for any axis that uses an
> estimated value for its dimension. For more information, see
> estimated(_:)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutitem/3199084-contentinsets

Things I've considered:

1: My only "solution" is to update my constraints in my cells to include these insets but I'd rather want to fix these insets on a higher level of abstraction (the UICollectionView that is).

2: Is it an option to assign a new layout to the collectionView without estimated values once the data has loaded? Would this come with performance issues?

3: This SO comment also mentions using contentInsets is not possible with estimated values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58568964/9339888, however no solution has been provided here.